# Nginx rewrite rule misses second capture group

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to rewrite my MediaWiki sitemap URLs to their proper location on S3 via Nginx, given that MediaWiki generates the sitemap.xml page with URLs like:
`https://subdomain.domain.net/databasename/sitemaps/sitemap-databasename-NS_0-0.xml.gz`; they are in the same format in S3, only the domain is 'static.domain.net' instead of the subdomain of the actual site.

I've tried several different rewrite rules, but this one has gotten me the closest to what I need:

```
        location ~ /([^/]+)/sitemaps/(sitemap-[^\/]+\.xml\.gz)$ {
        rewrite https://static.domain.net/$1/sitemaps/$2 permanent;
        }
```

But that rewrites the url to be:
`https://static.domain.net/databasename/sitemaps/`, without the second capture group. I've tested the regex in regex101, and it does seem to match both groups, but for some reason, Nginx is missing  the second capture group when it redirects — what is causing this? I simply need to capture the two groups and redirect the URL to static.domain.net instead of subdomain.domain.net.

Comment: You got `[^\/]` and `[^/]` in your expression. One of them is obviously wrong.

Comment: Also no leading `^` means your expression isn't properly anchored, are you certain that you didn't made that mistake on a different rule as well which matched in place of this one?

Comment: The only rules I have are the one in the answer below, and:

`location = /sitemap.xml { rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php last;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/sitemaps/(sitemap-[^./]+\.xml\.gz)$ https://static.domain.net/$1/sitemaps/$2 permanent;
```

or

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)/sitemaps/(sitemap-[^./]+\.xml\.gz)$ {
    return 301 https://static.domain.net/$1/sitemaps/$2;
}
```

Don't mix up the syntax - `rewrite` takes a regular expression as the first argument, and does *not* simply re-use capture groups from the outer context.

Comment: Ah, the 301 redirect seemed to do it! Thank you.